# Cambiar color de fondo de la fila de un DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

He configurado la primera columna de un `DataGridView` como `CheckBoxColumn`, al activar el `checkBox`, me gustaría que pintara toda la fila, de hecho me funciona, pero parece que no se aplican los cambios hasta que salgo de esa fila.
Os dejo el código que tengo a ver si me podéis echar un cable, he probado con `dataGrid.Refresh()` y `.Update()`, pero no consigo nada.
Muchas gracias.

```
private void dgvComandes_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    dgvComandes.EndEdit();
}

private void dgvComandes_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ColumnIndex == dgvComandes.Columns["colCheck"].Index)
    {
        bool sel = (bool)dgvComandes.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["colCheck"].Value;

        if(sel)
        {
            dgvComandes.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(106, 174, 144);
            dgvComandes.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }
        else
        {
            dgvComandes.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = dgvComandes.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor;
            dgvComandes.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = dgvComandes.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca este código en el **evento** **CellValueChanged** del **DataGridView**:

```
if (dataGridView2.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Column5")
{
   DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex];
   DataGridViewCheckBoxCell CellCheckBox = row.Cells["Column5"] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

   bool seleccionado = (Convert.ToBoolean(CellCheckBox.Value));

   if (seleccionado)
   {
      dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(106, 174, 144);
      dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
   }
   else
   {
      dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor =   dataGridView2.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor;
      dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = dataGridView2.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
   }
}
```

Este código lo que hace es que que pregunta si estamos parados en la **columna del CheckBox**, de ser cierto guardamos la fila en la **variable row** y casteamos a **DataGridViewCheckBox** la celda que tiene el **CheckBox**. Ahora preguntamos si el **CheckBox** está marcado o no, en dependencia de si está o no marcado ponemos un determinado color.

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero el cambio de color no es aceptado al momento de marcar o desmarcar el **CheckBox** sino cuando seleccionamos otra celda. Para solucionar esto vamos al **evento** **CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged** del **DataGridView** y ponemos este código:

```
if (dataGridView2.IsCurrentCellDirty)
{
    dataGridView2.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}
```

Básicamente lo que se hace es preguntar si hay algún cambio pendiente y de haberlo pues actualizamos.